# URL Rewrite with .htaccess From /user/projects/index.php?project_id=1 to /user/projects/1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having difficulties getting the correct code for my htaccess file to correctly rewrite my URLs.

**I'm trying to rewrite:** 
www.page.com/user/projects/index.php?project_id=1 to 
www.page.com/user/projects/1

Here's what I have in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^projects/([0-9]+)/?$    index.php?project_id=$1    [NC,L]
```

When I go to page.com/users/projects/1 I get a 404 error, so obviously the rewrite is not working properly. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `/user/projects/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/projects
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?project_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

From the root you can do.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+user/projects/index\.php\?project_id=([^&\ ]) 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/projects/([0-9]+)/?$ /user/projects/index.php?project_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not working. Previously I had it rewriting and removing the .php extension and it worked fine. I've added the .htaccess to the /user/projects folder but no luck.

Comment: You can try it from the root .htaccess file like the other example.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and make sure you .htaccess is working

Comment: My php was coded with the previous rewrite in mind, is there a way to combine the two? Here's what I had for the previous one. http://pastebin.com/k7Xyc4V0

Comment: so when you said not working what did it do? and where in your .htaccess did you put the rules?

Comment: and where exactly is your .htaccess file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80830/discussion-between-jayson-h-and-panama-jack).